# Why inside GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter list of marker not working?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I am working on Custom marker on Google map, but i have only one doubt why list of markers details are not coming inside GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter because when i am showing the data on default marker at that time all data showing perfectly.

```
for (int i = 0; i < mStringLocation.getMerchants().size(); i++) {

   double latitude = mStringLocation.getMerchants().get(i).getLocation().getLatitude();
   double longitude = mStringLocation.getMerchants().get(i).getLocation().getLongitude();

   final String name = mStringLocation.getMerchants().get(i).getName();

   LatLng latLng1 = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);

   MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions();
   markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.marker_icon));
   markerOptions.position(latLng1);
   //markerOptions.title(name);
   map.addMarker(markerOptions);

   map.setInfoWindowAdapter(new GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter() {
     @Override
     public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
           return null;
     }

     @Override
     public View getInfoContents(Marker marker) {

          View view = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.map_marker_layout, null);

            mNameTxt = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.name_txt);

            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            mNameTxt.setText(name);

            return view;
         }
   });

   map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
         Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "" + name, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
     }
  });
}
```

But when i am using Custom marker at that time it if you tap on any of the marker then it will show the last index value of the array.

Please kindly go through my post and let me know if you have any solution.

Comment: You have no code in your question that demonstrates "if you tap on any of the marker then it will show the last index value of the array".

Comment: hey thanks nothing simple on default marker if you tap on any item it will show the details but when i am doing inside GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter if you tap on any of the item it will show the last value

Comment: You may have an easier time getting help if you edit your question and provide the code for "if you tap on any of the marker then it will show the last index value of the array". I would guess that this is your `onInfoWindowClick()` method of your `OnInfoWindowClickListener`. You can see an example `onInfoWindowClick()` method in [this activity](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/master/MapsV2/Popups/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/mapsv2/popups/MainActivity.java) from [this sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Popups).

Comment: hey i have updated my post please go through it again

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setInfoWindowAdapter()` several times. You need to call it just once.

Similarly, you are calling `setOnInfoWindowClickListener()` several times. You need to call it just once.

Move those calls outside of your loop. Use the `Marker` object passed into `getInfoContents()` and `onInfoWindowClick()` to identify what you need to do in those methods. [This sample app](https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/MapsV2/Models) demonstrates how to use model objects from `getInfoContents()`, using a `HashMap` keyed by the `Marker` id.